# How to align divs horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a series of divs that is horizontal align and only show 1 div that cover the whole screen.

Something like

```
div1    div2   div3    div4     div5…
```

Only show 1 div in the screen unless user click next.

My html

```
<section id='contents-wrapper' class='container'>
<article class='row'>
   <div>

   </div>
</article>

<article class='row'>
   <div>

   </div>
</article>

<article class='row'>
   <div>

   </div>
</article>

<article class='row'>
   <div>

   </div>
</article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.row{
float: left;
min-width: 600px;
min-height: 800px;
width: 100%
}
.container{
width: 10000px;
}
```

How do I only show 1 div at a time on all device and screen resolution?

Comment: trying to make a slider or something? what is the reason to float every div left if you're only showing one? why not use `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0` inside a container and show/hide your rows on event?

Comment: I don't understand. `series of divs that is horizontal align and only show 1 div that cover the whole screen.`? What happens to the rest of the divs, then?

Comment: Why is your container width 10,000px wide?

Answer (score 1):

remove

> width:100%

from class  ".row",

this makes every article  width = 10000px

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
.row {
  display: inline-block; // as mentioned by bjb568
}
```

Also, remove all those `article` tags and add just one `article` tag and add all the `div` tags as its child elements.

Comment: Should be inline-block.

Comment: @bjb568 yes it can be, but only inline would also do that :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan no, it won't. `inline` elements can't have a specified width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.theContainer {overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;}
.theDivs {display: inline-block; width: 100%;}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('p').onclick = function() { //Back
    document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft = Math.round(document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft/document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth-1)*document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
}
document.getElementById('n').onclick = function() { //Forward
    document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft = Math.round(document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft/document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth+1)*document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KWwZP/